# CPU not powering up

Tags: troubleshooting, cpu, power-supply

Tried disconnecting the PSU and checked it by shorting green and black wires. It is working. However, when I connect it back to the motherboard and try to switch on the computer, all I hear is a faint click sound. The light at the back of the PSU turns off as well. Of course, the CPU does not power on. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a failing power supply, but it could also be a bad mother board. Most modern power supplies shut down when there is a short. The only way to know for sure is to get another power supply or another mother board.

Comment: I tried using another power supply as well. The problem persists.

Comment: Sounds like a short on the mother board. Try removing all cards, drives, and so on to make sure it is not one of them, but most likely it is the mother board.

Comment: I tried removing all the cards, RAM modules, however, the problem still persists. Most probably it is the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Dead motherboard? Are there any diagnostic lights on the motherboard? I'm assuming it doesn't make any beeping sounds. Might want to try a different power supply as well: just because it has power, doesn't mean it has *enough* power, or that the motherboard isn't reading some weird power condition and shutting itself down.

Comment: Used another power supply. The problem persists. There are no beeps. I did not notice any light on the motherboard.

Comment: Sounds like a motherboard problem to me.

Comment: Looks like the motherboard has broken down.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your motherboard is broken. If it is making beep sound and the power LED is on there is a chance that your motherboard is fine.

Check if your power supply is working by attaching it to another motherboard. If the power supply is working than check the RAM is working by putting it in a friends PC.

In most cases, the CPU is not faulty and the fault is elsewhere.

Comment: There are no beeps. Checked with different power supply as well. I guess it is a fault with the motherboard.